# Pentaho PDI Failed to load ESAPI.properties as a classloader resource

Tags: pentaho

I am running a fresh install of Pentaho Data Integration 5.0.1.A Stable from:
http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/
on my macbook pro, java 1.7.0_25, and I keep seeing this error in the console:

```
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: 
/Applications/pdi-ce-5.0.1.A/data-integration/ESAPI.properties
Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi/ESAPI.properties
```

What are the ESAPI.properties used for? What should they be set to by default?
thanks, -John

Comment: at the time of launching spoon you are getting this error?
and spoon is working or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug ([PDI-10568](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-10568)) that should be fixed in an upcoming release. As a work around, try putting the default [ESAPI](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/configuration/esapi/ESAPI.properties) and [validation](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/configuration/esapi/validation.properties) properties in your `$HOME/.esapi/` folder. Create one if it doesn't already exist.

*Background: ESAPI is an Enterprise Level Security library used by Pentaho webservices to properly encode URLs and HTML content, read more at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI*