# Error while executing pentaho transformation (talking to Sql server) through java program

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have a **Kettle (5.4.0.1)** transformation which executes query in **MS Sql server 2008 R2** in "Table Input" *task*. 
The task executes successfully in the Spoon UI directly or through Job.
Same transformation I want to execute through a Java program for which I got this code -

```
KettleEnvironment.init();
TransMeta metaData = new TransMeta("first_transformation.ktr");
Trans trans = new Trans( metaData );
trans.execute( null );
trans.waitUntilFinished();
```

But on executing it in a java program I get this error -

> 2015/07/30 20:08:34 - TestTransformation - Dispatching started for
>   transformation [TestTransformation] 2015/07/30 20:08:34 - XML Output.0
>   - Opening output stream in encoding: UTF-8 2015/07/30 20:08:34 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55
>   by buildguy) : An error occurred, processing will be stopped: 
>   2015/07/30 20:08:34 - Table input.0 - Error occurred while trying to
>   connect to the database 2015/07/30 20:08:34 - Table input.0 -
>   java.io.File parameter must be a directory.
>   [C:\Root\EclipseWorkSpace\TestProject\simple-jndi] 2015/07/30 20:08:34
>   - Table input.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection. 2015/07/30 20:08:34 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130,
>   build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : Error initializing
>   step [Table input] 2015/07/30 20:08:34 - TestTransformation - ERROR
>   (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) :
>   Step [Table input.0] failed to initialize!
>   org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:  We failed to
>   initialize at least one step.  Execution can not begin! at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.prepareExecution(Trans.java:1149) at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.execute(Trans.java:607) at
>   TestKettle.main(TestKettle.java:24)

What could be the issue here as the database connection happens successfully while executing through UI and same KTR file I am trying to execute in above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else facing this issue - The problem was the folder Simple-Jndi from Pentaho installation directory was required to be placed in the project folder which is not obvious from the error message above although it is mentioned in the error.

```
2015/07/30 20:08:34 - Table input.0 - java.io.File parameter must be a directory. [C:\Root\EclipseWorkSpace\TestProject\simple-jndi]
```

After this, I got two other errors which were more clear and was about files missing in the project folder - ESAPI.Properties and validation.properties. I downloaded them from link given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540683/pentaho-pdi-failed-to-load-esapi-properties-as-a-classloader-resource). Then the program ran successfully.

Comment: great. since you have found the answer.. request you to close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Table Input Step in the Ktr is not able to read the data.

Firstly, if you are calling a ktr file from Java code, make sure that the database driver jar files is properly imported/build inside the Java project. I mean import the "sqlserver" database jar file in the java project.

You may try reading this [blog](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/01/18/java-and-pentaho-kettle-executing-a-kettle-file-using-java/). I have used Maven to handle dependency of jars *(my db was : postgresql)*. And it works :)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for response, in my case I had included sql server jar file.